# for-each: get every 3rd item (split into 3 columns)

Tags: xslt, foreach

I have the following nodes in xsl:

```
<foo>
    <bar>1</bar>
    <bar>2</bar>    
    <bar>3</bar>
    <bar>4</bar>        
    <bar>5</bar>
    <bar>6</bar>    
    <bar>7</bar>
    <bar>8</bar>            
    <bar>9</bar>
</foo>
```

And would like to turn it into the following html:

```
<ul class="one">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>7</li>
</ul>
<ul class="two">
    <li>2</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>8</li>
</ul>
<ul class="three">
    <li>3</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

Having a hard time figuring out how to loop and get each third item, would like to do something like this:

```
<ul class="one">
<xsl:for-each select="exlt:node-set($blah)/foo/bar[X1]">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="node()"/></li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>

<ul class="two">
<xsl:for-each select="exlt:node-set($blah)/foo/bar[X2]">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="node()"/></li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>

<ul class="three">
<xsl:for-each select="exlt:node-set($blah)/foo/bar[X3]">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="node()"/></li>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>   

Where:
X1 = Every third item starting from position 1
X2 = Every third item starting from position 2
X3 = Every third item starting from position 3
```

Might need to use last(), but can't quite get that working correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In XPath, the condition will be:

```
not(position() mod 3)
```

or

```
position() mod 3 = 0
```

I don't see why you can't use `op:mod`.

**EDIT**: About **new question**, just substract the offset. So:

X1:

```
position() mod 3 = 1
```

X2:

```
position() mod 3 = 2
```

X3:

```
position() mod 3 = 0
```

**EDIT 2**: Now I understand your question.

Comment: Thought I could use mod too, but how would you loop through the other columns. Updated the question with more details. Maybe I am just missing something totally obvious.  Look at column 2 it should be #s: 2,5,8 these are not equal mod.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I totally misunderstood what mod did, thought it was only 1 or 0 depending on if the number was divisible. Only ever used it for alternating rows.

Comment: @Louis W: You are wellcome! From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#numbers : "The mod operator returns the remainder from a truncating division".

Answer (score 0):

Try [position() mod 3 = 1]