# XSLT dividing a list of nodes in thirds

Tags: xslt, html, nodes

How can I divide a list of nodes into thirds and put them into 3 columns

Comment: can you show your input and your desired output? This might become hsndy: http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/sect21.html

Comment: First duplicate found [for-each: get every 3rd item (split into 3 columns)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400074/for-each-get-every-3rd-item-split-into-3-columns)

Comment: One of Dimitre: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461866/xsl-list-divided-into-columns

Comment: Brilliant, Alejandro- ty

Answer (score -3):

you need smt like this:

```
<table><tr>
<xsl:for-each select="nodesPath">
   <xsl:if test='((position()-1) mod 3)=0'>
       <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</tr><tr>]]></xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
   <td>content</td>
</xsl:for-each>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: Horrible non-solution. disable-output-escaping is not needed to achieve this, and it only works in cases where the output of the XSLT transformation is serialized - which means it doesn't work if the result tree is used as input to another transformation, or rendered directly as is the case in Firefox. There are a few problems that can't be solved without disable-output-escaping. This isn't one of them.

Comment: ok, thanks guys, I'm not fixing the answer to show my mistake to all question readers